# Button's simple position

Tags: android, button, textview

I use this layout as a dialog. The problem is that the button appears to the right of the text.I tried with padding,position,gravity to make it appear UNDER the textview but I failed.
Hope you can help me....

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/layout_root"
      android:orientation="horizontal"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:padding="10dp"
      >
      <ImageView 
       android:id="@+id/image"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"
       android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
       />
      <TextView android:id="@+id/text"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:textColor="#FFF"
      />

      <Button
      android:id="@+id/ok"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:text="ok"

      />
      </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using a `LinearLayout` in a horizontal orientation.  That means it will list all views in a row horizontally in the order you put them.

You obviously want the image next to the text, so there are two ways to do that.  You can use two `LinearLayouts`.  The top one in a vertical orientation and the inner in a horizontal.  The inner will contain the image and text.  The outer will contain the inner and the button.

The second is to use `RelativeLayout` which allows you to set attributes like `layout_below` which will place the button below the text no matter where you put the text.

With two LinearLayouts:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/layout_root"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:padding="10dp"
      >
     <LinearLayout
     android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="horizontal"
     >
        <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#FFF" />
     </LinearLayout>
     <Button
        android:id="@+id/ok"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="ok"
      />
</LinearLayout>
```

With RelativeLayout (simpler):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout_root"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fil_parent"
    android:padding="10dp" >
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/image"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/image"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:textColor="#FFF" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/ok"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/image"
            android:layout_below="@id/text"
            android:text="ok" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add this to the `LinearLayout`:

```
android:orientation="vertical"
```

Comment: It's because now everything is stacked on top of each other.  You're using fill_parent everywhere on the height so things just get pushed off.

Comment: Also, you may need to add another LinearLayout which just surrounds your button and text.   Assign that as vertical orientation.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the items stacked vertically you will need to change the `orientation` property of the `LinearLayout`.

Try..

```
android:orientation="vertical"
```